# Arduino multiple serial/hid output

Tags: arduino, serial-port, usb, hid

Hello has anyone found a way to use an Arduino as a serial device and hid device at the same time?
I thought of a few solutions but didn't know the best way to go about it.
my goal is I need a serial device so the computer can send info to the Arduino but I also need an hid device.

can I use them both though 1 USB port? probably not
or
can I rig up another usb or serial port on the Arduino and use that as hid?
or
should I connect the Arduino to a teensy and use that for hid?

Thank you just trying to find the safest solution I'm making a custom fixture for my little laser engraver.

Comment: I never programmed a USB interface, but if you try to search for HID serial you will find some examples. If the HID specification allows for a serial interface, you can add it to the HID peripherals list and emulate it on the same USB Stack used for that

Answer (score 2):

I recommend getting an Arduino Leonardo, Arduino Micro, an [A-Star 32U4](https://www.pololu.com/category/149/a-star-programmable-controllers), or any other Arduino-compatible ATmega32U4 board.  These devices act as a USB serial port but they can also be an HID at the same time if you use the Keyboard or Mouse libraries that comes with the Arduino IDE.

Comment: David thank you, I think the teensy works the same way but ill research it. the Leonardo looks interesting.